# Updating text on a button using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to get the text on my button with the id `fixed-button` to update in a regular period using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#fixed-button').setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON("{{ url('schedulizer/cart') }}", function(data) {
                $(this).text(data.quantity);
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

However, the JS error I received is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setInterval is not a function
```

The issue is obvious - the `this` property has no `.setInterval` function. So the question is - how do I set the text on this button element using AJAX on a regular period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `setInterval` is not a jQuery function, it's a javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var $this=$('#fixed-button');
        window.setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON("{{ url('schedulizer/cart') }}", function(data) {
                $this.text(data.quantity);
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

DOC : **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't end up using intervals, since I realized I could trigger the changing of text on button press (I'm working on a cart module for my site, so adding to cart would trigger the text change instead of having an interval). This worked, though.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage   : glad to help :)